# JQuery: how to use enter keypress for href submition when focus is in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

I'm trying to use jquery and flask to change some values in my python script without refreshing the page. I can only submit when I click the link, or have the link selected when i press enter.

Is it possible to have a link submit on an 'Enter' press when the focus is on a different element only (i.e. the text box i'm using to set the value, but not anything else on the page) without making a separate link?

HTML:

```
 <h3>Change Value</h3>
   <p">New Value: <input type="text" size="5" name="entry"> <br>
     last entry: <span id="result">none</span> <br>
     <a href=# id="set_value">set value</a>
   </p>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var submit_form = function(e) {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_set_beam', {
        q: $('input[name="entry"]').val()
      }, function(data) {
        $('#result').text(data.result[0]);
        $('input[name=q]').focus().select();
      });
      return false;
    };

    $('a#set_value').bind('click', submit_form);
    $('input[type=text]').bind('keydown', function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        if ( $("set_value").is(":focus") ) {
          submit_form(e);
        }
        //elseif ( $("entry").is(":focus) ) {submit_form(e);}//something like this?
      }
    });
    $('input[name=q]').focus();
  });
</script>
```

PYTHON:

```
@app.route('/_set_value')
def set_value():
    """set a new value"""
    entry = request.args.get('entry', default='nothing', type=str)
    if entry == 'something':
        result = doSomething(entry):
    else:
        result = doSomethingEelse(entry)
    return jsonify( result=[entry] )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the default behavior of a `<form>` tag that will do exactly that, and bind your action to the submit event.

This way, you shorten your code and won't worry in the future about a new type of input being added and not supported by your script.

**HTML**

```
<form id="my_form">
   <h3>Change Value</h3>
   <p>New Value: <input type="text" size="5" name="entry"> <br>
     last entry: <span id="result">none</span> <br>
     <a href=# id="set_value">set value</a>
   </p>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('my_form').submit( function(e) { // submit handler
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_set_beam', {
        q: $('input[name="entry"]').val()
      }, function(data) {
        $('#result').text(data.result[0]);
        $('input[name=q]').focus().select();
      });
});
```

Personally, I prefer to use a lot of default behaviors, because they not only keep your code short but they end up aging better. When web conventions evolve, everything that is heavily custom made will fail to get better, while default stuff will keep changing and getting more and more easy to use and bug free over time.

Also, using a form input for something that is "submitable?" is better for the user, because it will honor any special handling or special treatment that the browser of his choice is adding to forms in general.